# Closure call with mismatched arguments: function '_MyAppState.build.<anonymous closure>'

Tags: flutter, closures, gesture

im getting this error while pressing on a button (no bugs on compiling)
it shows me an error at ()=> answerQuestions(answer['score'])

something going wrong about the anonymous function but i can't get it

> ```
> The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture:
> Closure call with mismatched arguments: function '_MyAppState.build.<anonymous closure>'
> Receiver: Closure: () => (int) => void
> Tried calling: '_MyAppState.build.<anonymous closure>(8)'
> Found: '_MyAppState.build.<anonymous closure>() => (int) => void'
> ```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import './question.dart';
import './answer.dart';

class Quiz extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Map<String, Object>> questions;
  final int questionIndex;
  final Function answerQuestions;

  Quiz({
    required this.questions,
    required this.answerQuestions,
    required this.questionIndex,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Question(
          questions[questionIndex]['questionText'] as String,
        ),
        ...(questions[questionIndex]['answers'] as List<Map<String, Object>>).map((answer) {
          return Answer(() => answerQuestions(answer['score']), answer['text'] as String);
        }).toList()
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import './question.dart';
import './answer.dart';

class Quiz extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Map<String, Object>> questions;
  final int questionIndex;
  final Function answerQuestions;

  Quiz({
    required this.questions,
    required this.answerQuestions,
    required this.questionIndex,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Question(
          questions[questionIndex]['questionText'] 
        ),
        ...(questions[questionIndex]['answers'] as List<Map<String, Object>>).map((answer) {
          return Answer(() => answerQuestions(answer['score']), answer['text'] );
        }).toList()
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: with removing 'as String' this error pop up on both questions and answer Lists 
The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.